# Regular expression for wraping all tr contains th tags in thead

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace-callback

I have a problem with regex, I need to wrap all the `tr` which contains `th` and put it in a `thead`. I have a variable `$html` which contains a html table like this:

```
$html ="
<table>
<tr>
  <th>header1</th> 
  <th>header2</th>
  <th>header3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>header21</th> 
  <th>header22</th>
  <th>header23</th>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>body1</td> 
  <td>body2</td>
  <td>body3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>body21</td> 
  <td>body22</td>
  <td>body23</td>
</tr>
</table>";
```

The regex i wrote is this

```
$html = preg_replace_callback(
'#(<tr.*?<th>.*?<th>.*?<\/tr>)#s', 
 function($match) {
        return '<thead>' . $match[0] . '</thead>';
    },
 $html);
```

But the result I get is different for what I want.
Now, I get `tr` into a different `thead`.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's not a good idea to try to parse HTML with regular expressions.**

That said, you need to get rid of one question mark, which gives you unlimited but as few as possible. For the space between the first and last `<th>` you want it to be as many as possible. This will to the trick:

```
              #this is supposed to be as greedy as possible
              #
~(<tr.*?<th>.*<th>.*?</tr>)~s
```

See https://regex101.com/r/fR1xB5/1

Comment: Thanks a lot, i get it. Everything is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

If have two table in page ,better try below one.

```
   (<tr>\s*(<th>((?!<tr>).)*</th>)+\s*</tr>)
```

example:https://regex101.com/r/fR1xB5/2